# Uploading a picture <form>

Tags: ruby, html, forms

I'm trying to add a picture uploader to my form and although I got it working I dont understand something.

So the form works when I have it like this:

```
<%= form_for(@project, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

But it does not when I add this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects" method="post">
<%= form_for(@project, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

What am I missing out?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Does it not send any request? Does it not send the params? Or wrong params?

Comment: Why are you opening 2 separate forms like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you do this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects" method="post">
<%= form_for(@project, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

you are opening a `<form>` tag in the first statement. When you render another form using rails helper `form_for`, it gets nested inside the first form. This is my guess from the limited question description.

You can try doing:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/projects" method="post"></form>
<%= form_for(@project, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Although you don't need to add that first form tag to make it work.